# How can I get a value displayed by "go env" from code?

Tags: go

I would like to explore the module cache on local machine, and access `go env GOMODCACHE`.

Is there an API to access the same values as those generated by "go env", using the current version of my go compiler when I compile my binary ?

I couldn't find a relevant package or type under the `go/*` packages from the standard library.

Comment: Are you looking for `os.Environ()`? https://pkg.go.dev/os#Environ There's also `os.Getenv()`.

Comment: @Zyl: no, I'm looking for the code that computes the default values when the env var is not defined

Answer (score 2):

`GOMODCACHE` is defined in [std/cmd/go/internal/cfg/](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/master/src/cmd/go/internal/cfg/cfg.go#L358)

```
     GOMODCACHE   = envOr("GOMODCACHE", gopathDir("pkg/mod"))
```

wgere `gopathDir` is

```
func gopathDir(rel string) string {
    list := filepath.SplitList(BuildContext.GOPATH)
    if len(list) == 0 || list[0] == "" {
        return ""
    }
    return filepath.Join(list[0], rel)
}
```

Both configuration and `gopathDir` are internal. No API exposes it.